# Mysql get last id of specific table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, last-insert-id

I have to get last insert id from a specific inserted table?.
Lets say i have this code:

```
INSERT INTO blahblah (test1, test 2) VALUES ('test1', 'test2');
INSERT INTO blahblah2 (test1, test 2) VALUES ('test1', 'test2');
INSERT INTO blahblah3 (test1, test 2, lastid) VALUES ('test1', 'test2', last id of blahblah);
```

How do i get the insert id of table blahblah in table blahblah3?
LAST_INSERT_ID() only gives you the last insert id

Regards, Simon :)

Comment: In your example simply switching the `INSERT INTO blahblah2` and the `INSERT INTO blahblah3` line would do the trick.

Comment: I can't do that in my coding, sry :/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [**LAST_INSERT_ID()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function.
Try this:

```
INSERT INTO blahblah (test1, test2) VALUES ('test1', 'test2');

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @blahblah;

INSERT INTO blahblah2 (test1, test2) VALUES ('test1', 'test2');

INSERT INTO blahblah3 (test1, test2, lastid) VALUES ('test1', 'test2', @blahblah);
```

Answer (score 14):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT id FROM blahblah ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to do it in a single statement use:

```
INSERT INTO blahblah3 (test1, test2, lastid)
VALUES ('test1', 'test2', (select MAX(id) FROM blahblah));
```

This way you don't need to save any variables beforehand which assures you'll get the latest ID at that exact moment.

Comment: I tried your example in this way, but it does not work:
 $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO products SET product_title='test'");
 $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO tags SET tag_values='test'");
 $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO iamges (images_path, product_id) VALUES ('blah', SELECT MAX(product_id) FROM products)'");

Comment: You forgot the brackets around the select, that's important. Use `$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO iamges (images_path, product_id) VALUES ('blah', (SELECT MAX(product_id) FROM products))");`. Also at the end you wrote `[...] products)'");`, I think it should be `[...] products)");` (remove the `'`).

Comment: Sorry to bring this back up, but can you tell me what should be outputted? I've got `MAX(ID)` and in PHPMyAdmin it brings up the required result (`2`) but I cannot get this in a script. Can you give some code to show how I could print the result (`2`)? Thanks alot :)

Comment: @Mattios550 Could you please be more specific? Why do you want to print the result? This code is for insertion :) If it's a matter of the scripting language you should think about asking it in the sections for that particular language.

Comment: @flu my aim is to simply get the largest entry in a column - in this case, 'id' - obviously, these are sequential. I know there are other ways, but I'd like to use `MAX(ID)` to get the highest ID then use `SELECT... WHERE id='$id'` when `$id` is `MAX(ID)` to get the latest entry in a table. Sorry if this is confusing & thanks for your reply :)

Comment: @Mattios550 If I got you right, then you're looking for `SELECT * FROM blahblah WHERE ID=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM blahblah)`.

Comment: Ahhhhhh - I had been trying `SELECT * FROM blahblah WHERE id=MAX(id)` - I don't think that works. Thanks alot for your help :)

Comment: @Mattios550 You're welcome! Vote me up, If my answer was helpful ;-)

Comment: @flu (select MAX(id) FROM blahblah), solved my problem .. good answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mysql_insert_id();` function to get a quick answer.

But if you are using a heavy traffic site, chances of in accurate results exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**LAST_INSERT_ID()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function.

```
INSERT INTO blahblah (test1, test 2) VALUES ('test1', 'test2');
    //this query will return id. Save it in one variable

 select LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

In short, save the last insert id in one variable and then use it in blahblah3

Comment: How do i do that? I doubt it :/

Comment: i was trying to tell you exactly what Saharsh Shah has mentioned in his answer. The only difference is that he has presented his answer in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

you can also find last id by query in codeigniter As

```
$this->db->order_by('column name',"desc");
   $this->db->limit(1);
 $id=  $this->db->get('table name');
```